custom Naming Strategy in MapStruct to Automatically map Fields with Prefixes
Can I use a Naming Strategy in MapStruct instead of manual mapping with @Mapping when field names follow a certain pattern?
For example, let's say I have an entity class where the field names follow a specific prefix rule, like so:
public class UserDTO {
    private String name;
    private String email;
    private String address;
    private String age;
}

public class UserEntity {
    private String usrName;
    private String usrEmail;
    private String usrAddress;
    private String usrAge;
}

Is it possible to use a custom Naming Strategy to map these fields instead of using the @Mapping annotation for each field manually?
Not just for this case, but assuming this prefix (like usr) is applied across the project, could I configure a Naming Strategy to handle this across all mappers?
I’ve tried configuring this in Maven, but it doesn’t seem to apply, and the Mapper gets implemented as an empty object. Any guidance on what could be wrong?

Here is the relevant part of my pom.xml:
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.11.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>17</source>
                <target>17</target>
                <annotationProcessorPaths>
                    <!-- MapStruct Processor -->
                    <path>
                        <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
                        <artifactId>mapstruct-processor</artifactId>
                        <version>1.4.1.Final</version>
                    </path>
                    <!-- Lombok -->
                    <path>
                        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        <version>1.18.28</version>
                    </path>
                </annotationProcessorPaths>
                <compilerArgs>
                    <arg>-Amapstruct.accessorNamingStrategy=com.mypackage.CustomAccessorNamingStrategy</arg>
                </compilerArgs>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>


Here is the custom NamingStrategy I code:
import org.mapstruct.ap.spi.DefaultAccessorNamingStrategy;
import javax.lang.model.element.ExecutableElement;
import org.mapstruct.ap.internal.util.IntrospectorUtils; // Use MapStruct's IntrospectorUtils

public class CustomAccessorNamingStrategy extends DefaultAccessorNamingStrategy {

    @Override
    public String getPropertyName(ExecutableElement getterOrSetterMethod) {
        String originalPropertyName = super.getPropertyName(getterOrSetterMethod);

        // Logic to remove prefixes
        if (originalPropertyName.startsWith("usr")) {
            return IntrospectorUtils.decapitalize(originalPropertyName.substring(3)); // Use MapStruct's IntrospectorUtils for decapitalize
        }

        return originalPropertyName; 
    }
}

import org.mapstruct.Mapper;
import org.mapstruct.Mapping;
import org.mapstruct.factory.Mappers;

@Mapper
public interface UserMapper {
    
    UserMapper INSTANCE = Mappers.getMapper(UserMapper.class);

    // This method will leverage the custom naming strategy
    UserDTO toDTO(UserEntity userEntity);

}

This is the usage part.:
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service
public class UserService {

    // Example usage
    public void exampleUsage() {
        // Sample data
        UserEntity userEntity = new UserEntity();
        userEntity.setUsrName("John Doe");
        userEntity.setUsrEmail("john@example.com");
        userEntity.setUsrAddress("123 Main St");
        userEntity.setUsrAge("30");

        // Convert to DTO using the INSTANCE directly from UserMapper
        UserDTO userDTO = UserMapper.INSTANCE.toDTO(userEntity);
        System.out.println("Mapped to DTO: " + userDTO);

    }
}

What I expected: Mapped to DTO: UserDTO{name='John Doe', email='john@example.com', address='123 Main St', age='30'}
result: Mapped to DTO: UserDTO{name=null, email=null, address=null, age=null}
